# Tableau: How to do conditional formatting of two different metrics by a Parameter

Tags: format, string-formatting, tableau-api

I have the parameter "Metrica", to see 1) headcount or 2) amount

I am using this formula to convert metrics to a string to show:

```
CASE [Métrica]
WHEN 'Conteo' THEN  str(COUNTD( [paracontar] ))
ELSE left(str( int( sum([Amount])/ 100000) / 10  ),6) + 'M'
END
```

When the parameter "Metrica" is on 'Conteo' the string is OK,
But when is not on 'Conteo' then string appears with so many decimals
like '2.399999M'

*How to do this conditional formating taking out many decimals into the string?*

[image: you can see the string with so many decimals]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CASE [Métrica]
WHEN 'Conteo' THEN  str(COUNTD( [paracontar] ))
ELSE str(ROUND((sum([Amount])/ 1000000)),1) + 'M'
END
```